# How to select an element which has () in it using JSON

Tags: jsonpath

I am using RestAssured for API automation and as a part of it I have to extract a value from the JSON reponse.

JSON reponse is given below

```
    {
"resourceName": "SERVICE_STATUS",
"records": [
    {
        "CREATED_DTTM": "2019-08-12T05:58:12.940Z",
        "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
        "SERVICE_EXECUTION_ID": "e760bed8-2ebb-4563-9812-7c0e5ed565cf",
        "OUTPUT_FILE(S)": [
            "FileC_FileA.csv"
        ],
        "SERVICE_ID": "EXCEL2CSV"
    }
],
"status": "SUCCESS"
```

}

I have to extract the value "FileC_FileA.csv" from the response, but when i do it via Json Path it is failing as "()" has special meaning in json path.

```
    JsonPath js1 = new JsonPath(statusrespstring);
    String outputfile = js1.get("OUTPUT_FILE(S)"); -----> This is failing
```

I have tried using

```
    String outputfile = js1.get("OUTPUT_FILE"+"("+"S"+")");
    String outputfile = js1.get('OUTPUT_FILE(S)');
```

But getting error as
: The parameter "S" was used but not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function

Someone please help, how to select a value whose key parameter has () in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

```
    ArrayList<String> outputfile = js1.get("records[0].'OUTPUT_FILE(S)'");
```

If the property has special character then surrounding with single quotes will work.

Reference : https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html